# React Navigation: Set header color before render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-navigation

I'm creating an app where the user can change the theme, I'm using react navigation's header and I know I can update `navigationOptions` by calling `setParams()` but calling it on `useEffect()` is too late, it renders the default color of the header before rendering the correct color.

I'm using functional state components by the way.

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setParams({
      backgroundColor: (theme === THEME_STANDARD) ? 'white' : Colors.appNight
    });
  }, [theme]);
```

Above is the code I use at the moment, it updates the header color automatically when I click the button for change theme, but when I navigate to this Screen, it shows the default color before showing the correct theme color. Do you guys have any idea on how to accomplish this? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

[`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) is probably what you are looking for, this runs code before the browser paints to the screen.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  navigation.setParams({
    backgroundColor: theme === THEME_STANDARD ? 'white' : Colors.appNight
  });
}, [theme]); // or empty dependency array if you only want it to run when the component mounts
```

Comment: Unfortunately this yields the same result as `useEffect` :/

Comment: Does it repro if you use a class-based component and set the params in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: was trying to look for functional component solution since im using `useContext` hooks